# Insert data into table using multiple stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to insert data from multiple stored procedures.

`Trial_Format_sp` returns 2 columns, `FieldA` and `FieldB`, but I want to add another column to indicate the company data come from.

This is my code and it don't work

```
create table TB
(
    Company nvarchar(max) ,
    FieldA  nvarchar(max),
    FieldB  nvarchar(max)
)

insert into TB
"ComA" , exec DB1.dbo.Trial_Format_sp

insert into TB
"ComB" , exec DB2.dbo.Trial_Format_sp
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your table TB consists of three columns. What have you written in your SPs? Can you show it? It must Select two columns.

Comment: table TB 3 columns
store procedure return 2 columns
then I want to add another 1 column before insert into table TB
to indicate data come from which company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot select from an EXEC, at least not without using [OPENQUERY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx). So, if you have that set up, you can try:

```sql
INSERT INTO TB (Company, FieldA, FieldB)
  SELECT "ComA", *
  FROM OPENQUERY(Local, 'exec DB1.dbo.Trial_Format_sp;');

INSERT INTO TB (Company, FieldA, FieldB)
  SELECT "ComB", *
  FROM OPENQUERY(Local, 'exec DB2.dbo.Trial_Format_sp;');
```

Another option is to create a table variable to load the results of each proc call into individually, and then dump those results along with the added column into the real table.

For example:

```sql
DECLARE @TempResults TABLE
(
  FieldA   nvarchar(max),
  FieldB   nvarchar(max)
);

INSERT INTO @TempResults (FieldA, FieldB)
  EXEC DB1.dbo.Trial_Format_sp;

INSERT INTO TB (Company, FieldA, FieldB)
  SELECT "ComA", tmp.FieldA, tmp.FieldB
  FROM @TempResults tmp;

DELETE FROM @TempResults;

INSERT INTO @TempResults (FieldA, FieldB)
  EXEC DB2.dbo.Trial_Format_sp;

INSERT INTO TB (Company, FieldA, FieldB)
  SELECT "ComB", tmp.FieldA, tmp.FieldB
  FROM @TempResults tmp;
```